# How to use Eclipse's embedded Jubula AUT Agent instead of the standalone agent?

Tags: unit-testing, functional-testing, jubula

I am trying to develop functional tests using Jubula's client API, but every example I have seen uses much out of Jubula standalone.  I would like to develop and run tests without having Jubula standalone installed.  Given that I have the necessary libraries from `jubula_8.5.0.127\development\api\JARs`, and Eclipse for Testers package, how could I start and connect to an AUT Agent without having Jubula standalone installed on my system?  I want a pure Java route and do not want to use the standalone AUT Agent executable (`.exe`).

It is perplexing to me that the help for Eclipse for Testers package of Eclipse has an entire topic on Jubula development which would depend on the standalone being installed.  Optimally, I'd like to be able to develop and run using the Jubula client API without using anything from the Jubula standalone.

Comment: Why don't you connect to the embedded AUT agent?

Comment: I am talking about doing this strictly through code using the jubula client api. What you ask is basically what I asked in my question. Without going into horrible detail, it takes a great deal of time to get software approved and installed on our development network. I already have Eclipse For Testers installed. I don't want to wait for months without end for the standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible that you can start the AUT agent out of java. So there is no need for the external autagent.
See the documentation for more details[1]

[1] https://help.eclipse.org/2019-03/topic/org.eclipse.jubula.client.ua.help/content/html/developerManual/clientAPI/ch02s08s01.html

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** *Use the feature (Eclipse for Testers) on tester's machines and install Standalone on your CI server.*

I believe you only need the Stand-alone version if your're automating test execution.

I mean if that's the case, then you can not avoid it; because it's the one containing native executables which can be invoked by frameworks like Ant, Maven, etc.

You can specify tests using Jubula's Java API with the feature version too, but if you want to execute them, then you have to select a database, connect to AUT and many further clicks with your mouse.

Comment: We are doing functional testing on a standalone desktop swing application, and I want the jubula solution in place so we can run gui tests. I'm fine with requiring a little interaction to kick it off.  Is is there any way to connect to the ITE's embedded Aut agent from the client API? Installing standalone jubula on our development server has the same hurdles as setting it up on each tester's machine.